Android Studio App Inspection not working
I am currently using a Mac device and running stable Android Studio Ladybug but unable to use App Inspection feature of Android studio.
By not working I mean I select the debuggable process it shows app inspection is running but the tabs of database inspector/ network inspector doesn't show up. It only shows up the text regarding which Android devices support being inspected by app inspector that is API level 26 and above. It was working back when I was using Android studio hedgehog.
I have tried Invalidate cache and restart, rebooting the android device uninstalling and reinstalling the debug app but nothing seems to be working.
Tried on multiple Android device running on Android 13-15
Can anyone please help!!

Please [edit] your question to clarify what it is that isn't working. Make sure to be clear enough so that we can try to reproduce the issue. If there are error messages then please post them as well (as formatted text, not as screenshots).

By not working I mean I select the debuggable process it shows app inspection is running but the tabs of database inspector/ network inspector doesn't show up. It was working back when I was using Android studio hedgehog
